# Javascript async functions with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, dictionary, asynchronous

I would like to populate a Javascript dictionary with restaurant chain names as keys and an object consisting of latitude and longitude as the values. I have the following code:

```
// create symbol table of name-coordinate pairs
var baseLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(window.latBase, window.lngBase);
var dict = {};
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(window.map);

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var singleChain = arr[i];
    console.log(singleChain);
    var request = {
        location: baseLocation,
        radius: '5000',
        query: singleChain
    };

    service.textSearch(request, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            dict[singleChain] = {
                lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()
            }
        }
    })

    // end for loop
}
```

The problem is, I now realize that the Google API request is not asynchronous, so each request is actually being made on only the last chain in arr[], ending up with a single-entry dictionary. What is the best way to implement an asynchronous function to get the desired functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a for loop which has an asynchronous function, you can go for a different approach. you can use recursive functions.

For example :

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3 , 4, 5];

function doSometing(i) {
  if(i >= arr.length) {
    return false;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    /* Do your computations */
    console.log(arr[i]);
    doSometing(i + 1);
  }, 2000);
}

doSometing(0);
```

Comment: It seems like your solution works because of the timeout, not due to recursion. Couldn't I add a timeout in the code I posted to the same effect? @Shubham

Comment: I changed to a recursive function and now it works like I want.

Comment: @samuelli97 I put `setTimeout` just to give you example that the output is an asynchronous. In your case `for` loop is not waiting for result to come.